# User with Browser Search Bar and a dropdown to switch between browsers

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer

We have a user on a Windows 10 machine with a search bar along the top of his one of his monitors. It looks like a Chrome search bar with shortcuts to Amazon and Facebook (where plugins would go). Besides the back and forward buttons there is a dropdown menu with the Chrome icon and it offers an option to open Internet Explorer as well.

If he creates a new tab it will show up under the search bar (which is locked at the top of the screen), drawn upside down.

If he clicks the Internet Explorer icon it opens internet explorer. If he clicks on the Chrome icon it opens a new Chrome window logged in to a specific user.

We can't see anything in the task manager or startup scripts to find this window.

Any suggestions for tracking this down? Not even our IT person recognizes it.

Comment: It's some sort of "helper" application. These commonly contain malware and used to be VERY common, though I haven't seen one myself in a few years. Use Task Manager or Process Explorer to identify the executable and learn more about it. Check for unrecognized entries in Programs and Features.

Comment: Other freeware options to find it are shown at https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-powerful-alternatives-windows-task-manager/ , such as Daphne http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php , TMX http://www.mitec.cz/tmx.html , System Explorer https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/System-Explorer.shtml , and the Open Source app Process Hacker  https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/